# Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade from 18.04 - amd radeon rx 580 not working

Tags: drivers, xorg, radeon, amd-graphics

After upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04 and uninstalling amdgpu-pro using their installer, I can no longer get a desktop environment.  On boot it goes to a black screen with a cursor and stays there.  If I hit cntrl-alt-f2 I get a shell and from there I can login.

When I do startx it errors out and the following is the xorg log:

```
$ cat .local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log
[  1099.264] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1099.275] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-177-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  1099.277] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu20 5.4.0-29-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 x86_64
[  1099.278] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic root=UUID=799a4e09-9f5e-4ce7-b573-a15c04e6034e ro quiet splash
[  1099.282] Build Date: 06 April 2020  09:39:29AM
[  1099.284] xorg-server 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  1099.286] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
....
[  1099.336] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (libsensors.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[  1099.336] (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver swrast
[  1099.336] (EE) GLX: could not load software renderer
[  1099.336] (II) GLX: no usable GL providers found for screen 0
[  1099.336] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[  1099.336] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[  1099.336] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[  1099.336] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[  1099.336] (II) AMDGPU(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[  1099.340] (EE) 
[  1099.340] (EE) Backtrace:
[  1099.340] (EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (OsLookupColor+0x13c) [0x563d637bedec]
[  1099.340] (EE) 1: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (funlockfile+0x60) [0x7f8957ba541f]
[  1099.340] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f89579e218b]
[  1099.341] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (abort+0x12b) [0x7f89579c1859]
[  1099.341] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  1099.341] (EE) 4: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (?+0x0) [0x7f89579c171a]
[  1099.341] (EE) 5: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__assert_fail+0x46) [0x7f89579d2f36]
[  1099.341] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  1099.341] (EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f89571662d0]
[  1099.341] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  1099.341] (EE) 7: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f89571664d0]
[  1099.341] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  1099.341] (EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8957174750]
[  1099.341] (EE) unw_get_proc_name failed: no unwind info found [-10]
[  1099.341] (EE) 9: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so (?+0x0) [0x7f8957177630]
[  1099.341] (EE) 10: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (MapWindow+0x20c) [0x563d6368a0bc]
[  1099.341] (EE) 11: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitFonts+0x355) [0x563d63661f75]
[  1099.341] (EE) 12: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7f89579c30b3]
[  1099.341] (EE) 13: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2e) [0x563d6364ba3e]
[  1099.341] (EE) 
[  1099.341] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  1099.341] (EE) Caught signal 6 (Aborted). Server aborting
[  1099.341] (EE) 
[  1099.341] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  1099.341] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1099.341] (EE) 
[  1099.353] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Things I have tried so far:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo usermod -aG video ubuntu
```

```
$ dmesg | grep amd
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-29-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-035) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #33-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 29 14:32:27 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-29.33-generic 5.4.30)
[    4.601167] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    4.601318] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0xe0000000 -> 0xefffffff
[    4.601318] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xf0000000 -> 0xf01fffff
[    4.601319] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0xf7e00000 -> 0xf7e3ffff
[    4.601320] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    4.604295] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: No more image in the PCI ROM
[    4.604351] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 8192M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F5FFFFFFFF (8192M used)
[    4.604352] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    4.604398] [drm] amdgpu: 8192M of VRAM memory ready
[    4.604399] [drm] amdgpu: 8192M of GTT memory ready.
[    4.605944] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is polaris10_smu
[    4.826564] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    4.864650] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    4.880243] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.35.0 20150101 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    8.112991] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: bound 0000:01:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
```

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: ef
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7e00000-f7e3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have

> [  1099.336] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (libsensors.so.4:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

in the errors, try solve that before

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search swrast_dri.so
sudo apt install ilibgl1-mesa-dri
reboot
```

have you updated everything ? have you got the last kernel 5.x kernel ?

Comment: so libgl1-mesa-dri was already installed.  However, to be thorough I went ahead and reinstalled it and it worked!  Thank you so much for your help, I now have a desktop environment back, woohoo.

Comment: actually, going back through history I see i did do a reinstall of libgl1-mesa-dri earlier which did not help.  I see after doing that I also did:
`sudo apt-get --reinstall install ubuntu-desktop`
`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware ubuntu-desktop`
`sudo ln -s /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_vcn.bin /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_vcn.bin`
`sudo reboot now`
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
`sudo apt install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri`
`sudo reboot now`

So not sure what exactly resolved, but the shotgun approach somehow got it going again.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning apt-file.